# Youtube API search with oauth 2 authentication

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

Why does the youtube API require 0Auth 2 authentication for searching by keyword? 
[This example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#search_by_keyword) shows that it is necessary.

Is it likely that there will be a Youtube search API that doesn't require authentication in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is incorrect [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) returns public data and there for does **not** require authentication it .

Search.list does how ever require a [public api key](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-create-public-api-key/) there is a difference between [Oauth2](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-oauth2/) and a public api key.

Comment: Okay, what was misleading me was that the javascript example on [that page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#examples) uses Oauth2 before doing the search query.

Comment: Agreed it's a bad example